# Use WhereHas with a model who may or may not have linked relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to display my data according to the following condition:

- If my data has an "order" relation, check if "order" hasn't the status "completed"
- If my data has not an "order" relation, simply retrieve the data as if there was no WhereHas

  ```
  Event::where('id', $id)->with(['persons' => function ($query) {

        // If Person has an order
        if ($query->has('order')) {
            $query->select('persons.id', 'name', 'title', 'status', 'title_prefixe', 'title_suffixe')
                ->whereHas('order', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('status', '!=', 'completed');
                });
            // If persons hasn't an order
        } else {
            $query->select('persons.id', 'name', 'title', 'status', 'title_prefixe', 'title_suffixe');
        }
    }])->first();
  ```

My problem :

I have the impression that it only takes into account my condition with my WhereHas. All "persons" without "order" are ignored and do not return results.

Why ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if `has` here returns a boolean or a `builder`. Maybe try `if ($query->order)`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution

I used `doesntHave` in conjunction with `orWhereHas` to create the desired query:

```
Event::where('id', $id)->with(['persons' => function ($query) {

          $query->select('persons.id', 'name', 'title', 'status', 'title_prefixe', 'title_suffixe')
              ->doesntHave('order')
              ->orWhereHas('order', function ($query) {
                  $query->where('status', '!=', 'completed');
              });
      }
  }])->first();
```